# Why "Wheels on the bus" and not "Wheels of the bus"?

Tags: prepositions

I´ve always wondered why the children song "Wheels **on** the bus" is not 
"Wheels **of** the bus".
Do you have an explanation?

Comment: The wheels **of** the bus could be flat and stored in a carton at the shop awaiting repair, in which case they wouldn't be rotating.  Wheels installed **on** the bus would be rotating.

Comment: The lyrics follow "horn on the buss.. Wipers on the buss.. and so on". So I think they just want to maintain  the scansion.

Comment: The wheels both belong to the bus and are attached to the bus. So either one would be OK from a language perspective. What you are asking about is word choice in lyrics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about word choice in lyrics, and does not ask a specific language-related question.